# Wget extract links and save them to a file

Tags: windows, url, grep, extract, wget

I need to download all page links from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki and save them to a file all with one command (with Wget for Windows).

The grep command is not recognized under Windows.

```
wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki -q -O - |grep -Po '(?<=href=")[^"]*'
```

The output of the links in the file does not need to be in any specific format.

What do you recommend ?

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple problems here:

1. Tool availability: `wget` and `grep` are not available on Windows by default. There exist numerous ports though, have a look [here](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/) and [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).
2. HTTPS verification: Wikipedia forwards from `http://` to `https://`, so you'll very likely have to add the option `--no-check-certificate` to the call (or provide a proper certificate store via `--ca-certificate`).
3. Escaping in Windows: to delimit parameters, don't use single quotes `'`, but double quotes `"`. You have to escape any double quotes inside the parameters like this `\"`.
4. Escaping in Windows: the caret character `^` has to be escaped like this: `^^`.

All in all this gives you:

```
wget --no-check-certificate "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki" -q -O - | grep -Po "(?<=href=\")[^^\"]*"
```